# R - Loop through multiple dataframes in a list

Tags: r, loops

UPDATE: results from dput( ldf[[1]] )

no prob. Here it is: 
    "A 04/18/2013 06:34:58 3D9.1C2D9F22C2", "A 04/18/2013 06:34:58 3D9.1C2D9F22C2", 
    "A 04/18/2013 06:38:24 3D9.1C2DDAE977", "A 04/18/2013 06:42:38 3D9.1C2DA0E0B5", 
    "A 04/18/2013 06:42:38 3D9.1C2DA0E0B5", "A 04/18/2013 07:07:49 3D9.1C2DD9D3CF", 
    "A 04/18/2013 07:07:49 3D9.1C2DD9D3CF")

- the problem may lie in some lines not being complete with these 4 variables. 
  *-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

I have gotten many pieces of this puzzle from this forum but I am still stuck. I am trying to loop through a list of 30 dataframes, the data of which have been read in from text files. I keep getting an error message and an empty destination dataframe at the end of the loop. Can anyone see where the problem lies?

Here is some sample data:

```
[73] "E 04/21/2013 14:05:01 3D9.1C2DF6F22D" "E 04/21/2013 14:05:01 3D9.1C2DF6F22D"
[75] "E 04/21/2013 14:47:54 3D9.1C2DF6F22D" "E 04/21/2013 14:47:54 3D9.1C2DF6F22D"

[[26]]
[1] "E 04/22/2013 17:07:02 3D9.1C2DDAC745" "E 04/22/2013 17:07:02 3D9.1C2DDAC745"
[3] "E 04/22/2013 17:07:02 3D9.1C2DDAC745"

[[27]]
[1] "F 04/17/2013 15:14:39 3D9.1C2D1DB26E" "F 04/17/2013 15:14:43 3D9.1C2D1DB26E"
[3] "F 04/17/2013 15:14:43 3D9.1C2D1DB26E" "F 04/17/2013 15:14:43 3D9.1C2D1DB26E"
```

Here is my loop code:

```
new <- data.frame()

for (i in 1:length(ldf)) {
 a[i] <- as.data.frame(ldf[i])
 a[i] <- as.data.frame(a[i][-1,])
 names(a[i]) <- "id"
 c[i] <- strsplit(as.character(a[i]$id)," ")
 reader[i] = sapply(c[i],function(x)x[1])
 date[i] = sapply(c[i],function(x)x[2])
 time[i] = sapply(c[i],function(x)x[3])
 code[i] = sapply(c[i],function(x)x[4])
 out[i] <- as.data.frame(cbind(reader[i],date[i],time[i],code[i]))

new <- rbind(new, out[i])
}
```

This is the error message I recieve:

```
Error in [<-.data.frame(`*tmp*`, i, 
value = list(c..A.04.17.2013.12.24.07.3D9.1C2D1DB26E....A.04.17.2013.12.24.07.3D9.1C2D1DB26E... = c(1L,  
: replacement element 1 has 337 rows, need 394
```

Thank you!

Comment: Try change `a[i] <- as.data.frame(ldf[i])` to `a[i] <- as.data.frame(ldf[[i]])`.

Comment: And why you are saving each step in the variables `a`, `c`, `out` ... ? If you don't use them, remove the index `[i]` too.

Comment: better you tell us *what you expect* from this. Amongst other things you shouldn't need to be using sapply in a loop, sapply is a looping construct in itself. If you tell us the expexcted output someone might be able to generate a more `R` oriented solution.

Comment: I'm looking to process each dataframe in the list ldf and append the results into one dataframe. Right now each dataframe has one long string of my 4 variables. I want to parse each variable out into new variables for each row, and then append the results together so I end up with one clean dataframe as opposed to a list of 30 dataframes. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want this:

```
ldf <- list(c("E 04/21/2013 14:05:01 3D9.1C2DF6F22D","E 04/21/2013 14:05:01 3D9.1C2DF6F22D","E 04/21/2013 14:47:54 3D9.1C2DF6F22D","E 04/21/2013 14:47:54 3D9.1C2DF6F22D"),
c("E 04/22/2013 17:07:02 3D9.1C2DDAC745","E 04/22/2013 17:07:02 3D9.1C2DDAC745","E 04/22/2013 17:07:02 3D9.1C2DDAC745"),
c("F 04/17/2013 15:14:39 3D9.1C2D1DB26E","F 04/17/2013 15:14:43 3D9.1C2D1DB26E","F 04/17/2013 15:14:43 3D9.1C2D1DB26E","F 04/17/2013 15:14:43 3D9.1C2D1DB26E"))

do.call(rbind,lapply(ldf,function(x) data.frame(do.call(rbind,strsplit(x," ")))))
   X1         X2       X3             X4
1   E 04/21/2013 14:05:01 3D9.1C2DF6F22D
2   E 04/21/2013 14:05:01 3D9.1C2DF6F22D
3   E 04/21/2013 14:47:54 3D9.1C2DF6F22D
4   E 04/21/2013 14:47:54 3D9.1C2DF6F22D
5   E 04/22/2013 17:07:02 3D9.1C2DDAC745
6   E 04/22/2013 17:07:02 3D9.1C2DDAC745
7   E 04/22/2013 17:07:02 3D9.1C2DDAC745
8   F 04/17/2013 15:14:39 3D9.1C2D1DB26E
9   F 04/17/2013 15:14:43 3D9.1C2D1DB26E
10  F 04/17/2013 15:14:43 3D9.1C2D1DB26E
11  F 04/17/2013 15:14:43 3D9.1C2D1DB26E
```

Note that all columns are of class factor.

Comment: +1 as I think this is what the OP wants as output, but they also claim their data is a list of dataframes, so you may have to update this to do something like run `apply` across each dataframe (as you can't pass a dataframe to `strsplit`)

Comment: @SimonO101 Ah, I think they are 1 column `data.frames` so replacing `x` with `x[[1]]` in the `strsplit` should suffice.

Comment: Ah ok! Just thought I'd mention it incase. :-)

Comment: Thank you for these suggestions. I'm trying to sort this out. I tried SimonO101's suggestions but received a long error message. And yes, James, as you say they are 1 column dataframes. I'm confused as to where I replace x with x[[1]] at. In each new variable that I create? I know some comments above indicate I should refrain from using sapply wihtin a loop. Do you agree? Thanks again!!

Comment: @yakamafish Replace it in the first argument to `strsplit`. You can still use `sapply` in a loop, but more often than not there will be a better way to approach the problem. In this case `do.call(rbind,c[[i]])` would do the trick I believe.

Comment: I replaced a[i] with a[[i]] in my first strsplit argument and received this error:  Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, value = list(`ldf[[i]]` = c(1L,  : 
  replacement element 1 has 337 rows, need 394

Comment: And it is possible in a list of data frames match iteratively for example If I had 5 data frames I want to match data frame 5 with data frame 4, 3, 2 and 1. For data frame 4 is the same but with data frame 3, 2, 1 @yakamafish

Answer (score 0):

Is `ldf` your list of dataframes? If so you are not indexing them properly. You are trying to operate on an object of class `list` still. Look at this toy example:

```
L <- list( x=matrix(1:4,nrow=2) , y=matrix(1:4,nrow=2) )
L
#$x
#    [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    3
#[2,]    2    4

#$y
#    [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    3
#[2,]    2    4

class(L[1])
[1] "list"
class(L[[1]])
[1] "matrix"
```

You are using a lot of looping constructs within a loop which doesn't make much sense, because they are supplied as convenience functions such that you don't have to use a loop. Using a subset of your data you can get what I believe are your desired results using an `lapply` to access each data.frame in your list, and then use`apply` across the columns of each dataframe to run `strplit` on them like this:

```
# Make a list of two data.frames using some of your data
dat1 <- data.frame( x = c("E 04/21/2013 14:05:01 3D9.1C2DF6F22D" , "E 04/21/2013 14:05:01 3D9.1C2DF6F22D") , y = c( "E 04/22/2013 17:07:02 3D9.1C2DDAC745" , "E 04/22/2013 17:07:02 3D9.1C2DDAC745") )
dat2 <- data.frame( x = c("F 04/17/2013 15:14:39 3D9.1C2D1DB26E" , "F 04/17/2013 15:14:43 3D9.1C2D1DB26E") , y = c( "F 04/17/2013 15:14:43 3D9.1C2D1DB26E" , "F 04/17/2013 15:14:43 3D9.1C2D1DB26E") )
dat <- list( dat1 , dat2 )


res <- data.frame( t( data.frame( lapply( dat , function(x) apply( x , 2 , strsplit , " " ) ) ) ) )
names(res) <- c( "Reader" , "Date" , "Time" , "Code" )
rownames(res) <- seq_len( nrow( res ) )
#  Reader       Date     Time           Code
#1      E 04/21/2013 14:05:01 3D9.1C2DF6F22D
#2      E 04/21/2013 14:05:01 3D9.1C2DF6F22D
#3      E 04/22/2013 17:07:02 3D9.1C2DDAC745
#4      E 04/22/2013 17:07:02 3D9.1C2DDAC745
#5      F 04/17/2013 15:14:39 3D9.1C2D1DB26E
#6      F 04/17/2013 15:14:43 3D9.1C2D1DB26E
#7      F 04/17/2013 15:14:43 3D9.1C2D1DB26E
#8      F 04/17/2013 15:14:43 3D9.1C2D1DB26E
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried this command: res <- data.frame( t( data.frame( lapply( ldf , function(x) apply( x , 2 , strsplit , " " ) ) ) ) ) but I received an error saying: Error in apply(x, 2, strsplit, " ") : dim(X) must have a positive length

Comment: @yakamafish did it work? if not, I made a tiny edit which should take care of the fact that your dataframes are only 1 column big (this would confuse the apply function!)

Comment: yes it is now above `apply(x[1]....` was the change. it should work on a 1 column dataframe now.

Comment: still getting this error:  Error in apply(x[1], 2, strsplit, " ") : 
  dim(X) must have a positive length

Comment: I received this error with the new edit: Error in x[, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions

Comment: @yakamafish ok, if you want it sorted properly I suggest you give us the structure of your data by pasting the output from `dput( ldf[[1]] )` into your question above. I am just guessing at what you have at the moment!

Comment: I will have to play around some more. You have given me lots of suggestions to work from. i don't want to take up more of your time. I sincerely thank you for your help!

Comment: @yakamafish fine. but if you just copy/paste like I said then it can be sorted really quickly, but if you can't (confidentiality etc) then no worries!

Comment: @yakamafish I am looking for some out put like `structure(list(x = structure(c(1L, 1L), .Label = "E 04/21/2013 14:05:01 3D9.1C2DF6F22D", class = "factor"), 
    y = structure(c(1L, 1L), .Label = "E 04/22/2013 17:07:02 3D9.1C2DDAC745", class = "factor")), .Names = c("x", 
"y"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")`

Comment: @yakamafish also it was pretty important to tell us that not all lines have *all* the variables!!!!!!!!